# Function without parameters, and calling a function inside

Tags: postgresql

I'm new with PostgreSQL and feeling quite overwhelmed..

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

#### Wanted outcome

| year | descrip | percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Word word word | 0.10 |
| 2018 | Word word sad | 0.80 |
| 2017 | Word empty word | 0.15 |
| etc | Word word word | 0.41 |

Where percent is function_A divided by function_B** (function_A / function_B).

#### I already have the functions

- **function_A** has two parameters : year (extracted from status_date) and code. Returns the number of orders defined by the previous
  parameters.
- **function_B** has one parameter: year (extracted from status_date).
  Returns the total number of orders by year.

#### Function

This is what, wrongly, I did so far - including code from nbk's original [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291062):

The function shouldn't have any parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION summary_orders()
RETURNS TABLE (retyear numeric, order_desc text, percentage bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    retyear numeric DEFAULT 0;
    descrip text DEFAULT 0;
    percent bigint DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    RETURN
        QUERY SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM created_dt) as numeric),
                order_desc as text,
                ROUND(function_A(inyear,incode))::decimal / function_B(inyear) as percent
        FROM orders o
        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.creation) = inyear
        AND o.order_code = incode
        AND o.descrip 
        GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM o.creation), o.code
        ORDER BY retyear ASC;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### To call the function I expect to use:

```
SELECT * from summary_code()
```

My data looks something like this:

#### 'orders' Table

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    code INT NOT NULL, 
    service_id INT NOT NULL, 
    descript CHARACTER VARYING(50), 
    creation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    status_date TIMESTAMP,
    created_user INT
    );
```

#### Records

```
INSERT INTO orders 
(id, code, service_id, descript, creation, status_date, created_user) 
VALUES 
(100,2394,558151,'Requested not today','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Fulfilled blue squit','2018-06-16 11:12','2018-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Requested blue kit','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2395,558152,'Requested pony','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2396,558153,'Requested sauron','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Requested I'm tired','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1);
```

I'm sorry if this comes as a little cheeky, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>     id INT NOT NULL, 
>     code INT NOT NULL, 
>     service_id INT NOT NULL, 
>     descript CHARACTER VARYING(50), 
>     creation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>     status_date TIMESTAMP,
>     created_user INT
>     );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders 
> (id, code, service_id, descript, creation, status_date, created_user) 
> VALUES 
> (100,2394,558151,'Requested not today','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
> (100,2394,558151,'Fulfilled blue squit','2018-06-16 11:12','2018-06-18 14:08',1),
> (100,2394,558151,'Requested blue kit','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
> (100,2395,558152,'Requested pony','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
> (100,2396,558153,'Requested sauron','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
> (100,2394,558151,'Requested I''m tired','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION function_A(in numeric, in int,out noorder int)
>     AS $$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  "status_date") = $1 AND "code" = $2 $$
>     LANGUAGE SQL;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION function_B(in numeric,out noorderyear int)
>     AS $$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  "status_date") = $1  $$
>     LANGUAGE SQL;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION summary_orders()
> RETURNS TABLE (retyear numeric, order_desc TEXT, percentage numeric) AS $$
> DECLARE
>     retyear numeric DEFAULT 0;
>     descrip TeXT DEFAULT 0;
>     percent numeric DEFAULT 0;
> BEGIN
>     RETURN
>         QUERY SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM status_date) as numeric) teayear,
>                 MIN(descript) as descrip,
>                 ROUND(Max(function_A(CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM status_date) as numeric),code))::decimal / function_B(CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM status_date) as numeric)),2) as percent
>         FROM orders o
>         GROUP BY teayear
>         ORDER BY teayear ASC;
> END;
> $$
> LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM summary_orders()
> ```
>
> ```
> retyear | order_desc           | percentage
> ------: | :------------------- | ---------:
>    2018 | Fulfilled blue squit |       1.00
>    2019 | Requested blue kit   |       0.60
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20fc9f0102797c790abfaae83acda749)*

Comment: Description is not defined and you wanted result also yields no information what the text should be. so on that part you have to do some changes